# Feasibility of Google OR Tools for large scale FJSSP

Tags: python-3.x, job-scheduling, or-tools, cp-sat

I want to solve FJSSP and have made a working code snippent for the same. I want to know how scalable is it for large problems (for 10 X 10 and 100 X 100). How much time will it take to solve?

Will it be possible to get results in acceptable time (less than 10-15 minutes, or even less)

Answer (score 0):

This question is to vague. What is acceptable time? Time to what?

There are smaller problem that 100x100 that CP-SAT does not prove optimality on 24h with 32 cores.

The problem are still open problem, so nobody knows the optimal value.